# How to solve changing interface language in MS Publisher (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, office365, language, microsoft-publisher

In Office 365 MS Publisher, after pressing the button **Edit Links to Files**, the dialog appears in Russian. I would like it to be in English

[image]

[image]

Other Publisher dialogs display in English fine.

I followed the Microsoft [tutorial](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/change-the-language-office-uses-in-its-menus-and-proofing-tools-f5c54ff9-a6fa-4348-a43c-760e7ef148f8), particularly for changing **Display language**, and all seems correct:

[image]

However, the dialog is yet not in English.

I have an old good official Windows 7 Home Premium, in Russian. Windows language settings:

[image]

Is there a way to show that dialog in English, and how?

Comment: Why downvoting? Please explain

Comment: Not me. Someone perhaps didn't like the Russian dialogs. Switch perhaps Windows to English for the purpose of this question.

Comment: Question: In *Settings > Time & Language > Language*, do you have under "Preferred languages" a message in yellow or a button named "Group related languages"?

Comment: @harrymc Let him upvote rather than downvote then because I also want the dialog in English

Answer (score 0):

Open the Publisher- go to **File**- **Save As**- Open Desktop(also other folders)- the dialog box is in English, back to the file and open **Edit link to file** option, it will change to Office Language but not the Windows system Language.

[image]